# I have a question about finite dimension norm linear spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let R is linear space over the field Q and Q is a finite dimension subspace of R the what about the completeness of Q ?? Since we know that any finite dimension norm space is complete but here Q is not complete but it's dimension is finite????

Comment: Are Q and R related to the rational numbers and the real numbers in any way?

Comment: Yes sir R is the set of real numbers and Q is the set of rational numbers

Answer (score 2):

Every finite dimensional normed vector space is complete over the fields of real or complex numbers, but this result does not hold for general fields.

For instance, just consider the one-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{Q}$ with the absolute value as a norm. Of course, this normed vector space is not complete.